# Max Acceleration on an incline? (2010 F=ma #8)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

(From 2010 F=ma, #8)
A car attempts to accelerate up a hill at an angle θ to the horizontal. The coefficient of static friction between the
tires and the hill is µ > tan θ. What is the maximum acceleration the car can achieve (in the direction upwards
along the hill)? Neglect the rotational inertia of the wheels.

(A) $g tan θ$

(B) $g(µ cos θ − sin θ)$

(C) $g(µ − sin θ)$

(D) $gµ cos θ$

(E) $g(µ sin θ − cos θ)$

My instinct said to do 
$F_{net} = ma = F_{friction}-mgsin θ$

But why would solving for acceleration here be the maximum acceleration possible?

Comment: Draw a free body diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum acceleration will happen just before the wheels start to skid - so when you write down the balance of forces, you will find the maximum possible acceleration (accelerate faster requires more force, and that will cause slipping)

The normal force is constant at $F_n = mg\cos\theta$; the force of gravity along the slope will always add a component of force $mg\sin\theta$ "down hill". Now you try to accelerate, so you have an addition $m\cdot a$ along the slope.

The maximum acceleration is reached when the two forces along the slope are equal to the force of friction:

$$m(g\sin\theta + a) = mg\mu\cos\theta$$

You can rearrange that to get one of the answers listed...